# Android kotlin - RecyclerView find out what exactly inside item was clicked in activity/fragment

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

This is the adapter:

```
class ToplistAdapter(val context: Context, private val users: MutableList<Toplist>, val itemClick: (Toplist) -> Unit) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ToplistAdapter.ViewHolder>(){

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val user = users[position]
        holder.percent.text = user.prozent
        Picasso.get().load(user.image).into(holder.imagee)

        holder.bind(users[position], context)
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = users.size

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.toplist, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view, itemClick)
    }

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View?, val itemClick: (Toplist) -> Unit) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView!!){

        val percent = itemView!!.text_percent
        val imagee = itemView!!.image_view

        fun bind(toplist: Toplist, context: Context){
            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                itemClick(toplist)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this in fragment:

```
            adapter = ToplistAdapter(activity!!, users) {
                // Profile(it.userid.toString())
            }

            recyclerView.adapter = adapter

            recyclerView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(activity!!, 2)
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
```

I know how to set onClicklistener inside `onBindViewHolder` and **find out if either `text_percent` or `image_view` was clicked** but how can I do this **inside fragment** besides getting `userid` etc?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

The requested data model class:

```
data class Toplist(
        val image: String,
        val prozent: String,
        val userid: Long
)
```

Answer (score 2):

In your adapter create  ClickListener

```
   open interface ClickListener {
        fun onClick(position: Int)

    }
```

then implement your adapter

```
class ToplistAdapter(val context: Context, private val users: MutableList<Toplist>, val listener: ClickListener) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ToplistAdapter.ViewHolder>(){

   companion object {
        var clickListener: ClickListener? = null
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

    clickListener = listener
    val user = users[position]
    holder.percent.text = user.prozent
    Picasso.get().load(user.image).into(holder.imagee)

    holder.bind(users[position], context)
    holder.imagee.setOnClickListener { 
        itemClick(users[position]) 
    }
   holder.imagee.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
            override fun onClick(v: View?) {
                if (clickListener != null)
                    clickListener?.onClick(position)
            }
        })



    }
```

then your fragment or Activity add

```
     adapter = ToplistAdapter(activity!!, users, object : ToplistAdapter.ClickListener {
            override fun onClick(position: Int) {
               val user=users[position]
               val userid=user.userid
            }
        })
```

Comment: the userid inside users.userid.toString() is unresolved reference and how would I find out if text_percent or text_view was clicked?

Comment: what for? I think you don't fully understand what I want, I edited the question a bit and also showed the data model just in case

Comment: Where exactly do I place open interface ClickListener? I tried different places and get error: Classifier 'ClickListener' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here. And also: Unresolved reference: itemClick

Comment: I already struggled for many hours with this, I think it's just impossible to find out what item element was clicked in fragment instead only adapter

Comment: view holder itemClick  remove it.use onBindViewHolder onclick listener

Comment: In Fragment    val user=users[position]  is your clicked value

Comment: But I get Unresolved reference: itemClick inside adapter. And what do you think would I get with user=users[position]? Information which element I clicked or the value/s of image/userid/prozent???

Comment: this code for  image click. check from first you changed all the place code would be correct

Comment: dude I think you still don't understand what I need. I need to find out INSIDE THE FRAGMENT what ELEMENT (either text_percent OR image_view) was clicked. Not only the user values, I got them from begine with